# How can I generate all possible states of an n-length binary string?

Tags: javascript

There are tons of questions like this here, I know, but I just read through 6 of them and they mostly pertain to generating all combinations of the character set with any length (`a,b,c -> a, ab, abc ...`) and / or only of the length of the string or list provided.

What I'm trying to figure out how to do is represent all possible binary strings of a given length (encoded in base 2), and after reading all the questions I could find about this, I'm still having trouble figuring out how the function should be designed.

My goal is to have a function like:

```
var list = generateStates(3); // -> ['000', '111', '011', '001', '100', '110', '101', ... ]
```

The tricky part is I think I need to do this without recursion, because I want to do this with longer binary strings and the recursion can't be sustained that deep (without exceeding the maximum call stack).

Comment: See edit at end, I should've mentioned that to begin with.

Comment: What max length are you shooting for (that's too much for recursion?)

Comment: where is actually the problem? you could easily generate from a given state the next state by adding one.

Comment: @NinaScholz wait, that sounds simple, and Im probably an idiot for not understanding this, but Im having trouble visualizing how that's done. Seems like theres more to it than just adding  each time. Could you show it?

Comment: @Tor Maybe 300-400 length chunks. But that adds up to, I think, over 100K recursions deep, right, or am I wrong?

Comment: recursion would only go as deep as there are digits in one combination.

Comment: If you want chunks of up to length 300, then you aim to produce 2^300 strings in the results array, which takes more bytes of memory than there are atoms in the known universe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function generateStates(n){
  var states = [];

  // Convert to decimal
  var maxDecimal = parseInt("1".repeat(n),2);

  // For every number between 0->decimal
  for(var i = 0; i <= maxDecimal; i++){
    // Convert to binary, pad with 0, and add to final results
    states.push(i.toString(2).padStart(n,'0'));
  }

  return states;
}
```

Comment: This throws a process out of memory error in Node.js, is generating all combinations of a 300 length binary string too much to be feasible? I thought it was just ~100K combinations. Seems doable.

Comment: 300 length binary is waaaaaayyyyyy too much to ask for: every binary character can have two values (0 or 1), so that amounts to 2^300 combinations, which is roughly 10^90. That is more than there are atoms in the known universe.

Comment: @Viziionary You're just a *few* orders of magnitude off in your estimation. The number of possible values of a `n` length string of binary digits is 2^n. So 2^300 is about **2.037*10^90**.

Comment: RE: Viz, I think it'd actually be many many many magnitudes higher than that. By generateStates(20) you're already at 1,048,576 different combinations.

Comment: @8bittree Ohh shit, I was thinking since it was just a 2 character set, it would be 300^2. I'm so bad at math :P

Comment: @Viziionary Nope, 300^2 would be all 2-character strings, made from a 300 character alphabet.

Answer (score 3):

An attempt

Starting with a given n = 3 and take following values

> ```
> binary  decimal
> ------  -------
>   000       0
>   001       1
>   010       2
>   011       3
>   100       4
>   101       5
>   110       6
>   111       7
> ```

With this in mind, you could generate from a given combination the next value by adding one. (Or if you take an array, then perform a `reduceRight` and build a new array.)